# MYSQL LEFT JOIN returning duplicate table a results

Tags: php, mysql, sql, select, left-join

Update Scroll to bottem for sql Code and output
I recently started working on an apartment database. The database contains 2 tables

Table a "property" stores information about apartment complexes basic (contact info and photos). It is referenced by the column `propid`

Table b "floorplans" stores information about individual units for rent. pricing information, square footage, and apartment type. The `floorplan` table also is referenced by the column `propid` to allow us to link the 2 tables together. It also has its own unique identifier but it is unused.

There are typically 5-10 floorplans per complex.

I am creating a frontend search interface for our customers on our website. I need the ability to search for a property that has floorplans that meet the search criteria. but when performing the join statement I noticed it kept giving me a list with the same property in it each time one of its floorplans were found to match the search criteria.

I did some research on the subject. Most common answer use SELECT DISTINCT.

The problem is that I need more then just the propid to be returned as a result.

I tried doing something like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT (p.propid), p.*, f.* FROM property AS p 
LEFT JOIN floorplans AS f ON p.propid = f.propid
WHERE f.pricespecial BETWEEN [min_price] AND [max_price];
```

`[min_price]` and `[max_price]` are provided by the user.

The intended result would be a list of all properties that have floorplans that meet all users search criteria. But I do not want the same property returned for every single matching unit.

When I run this query I still get duplicate properties

In the past I just simply ran a filter script on the xml feed containing the data. The script would determine the highest and lowest price units in the givin property and add those values to 2 newly created columns on the property table `price_min`, and `price_max`. until now this was good enough but the company has been pushing for more accurate search results.

The only other option I see is to just run the query with only the DISTINCT propid's returned. Then run a second query to retrieve the actual data.

I.E.

```
$sql = "SELECT DISTINCT p.propid FROM property as f" .
       "LEFT JOIN floorplans AS f" . 
       "WHERE f.price BETWEEN " . $_REQUEST['price_min'] . " AND " . $_REQUEST['price_max'] . "
```

EDIT******

some sample output using a newly revised sql statment.

```
propid  name    pricespecial  
4230A   2222 Smith Street   $1225-1450  
4230A   2222 Smith Street   $1895-2045  
4230A   2222 Smith Street   $2220  
4679A   City Place Midtown  $1230-1599  
4679A   City Place Midtown  $1595-1650  
4679A   City Place Midtown  $1699-2195  
4572A   Gables Memorial Hills   $1308-2159  
4572A   Gables Memorial Hills   $2050-2693  
4606A   Venue Museum District   $1535-1930  
4606A   Venue Museum District   $1980-2550
```

I was having troubles posting this as a comment so I just edited my question.

Comment: You've included `f.*` in your `SELECT`, but it's not clear to me whether you want those values to be returned. Do you?

Comment: Yes I want all values from both tables but I only want distinct propid column. The output is a list of the propertys containing details on the floorplan so eventually I will filter out the fields that i don't need from the floorplans table but for the sake of simplicity lets assume I want all data from both tables but only one from each property entry.

Comment: I don't think I follow. If floorplans has 5 records for a given property, you say you want to see the 5 floorplans but only 1 property? Maybe try adding a table with some sample results that you expect to see.

Comment: So if two floorplans exist for a single property, you want the data from the floorplans, but without repeating the property info? Does your code then know that the floorplan in the second row of data is matched to the previous record's property?

Comment: Side note, just wait for someone to alter the request and set `price_max` to `1; DROP DATABASE; --`.

Comment: @Dean: What happens with a floorplan that has the same properties as other floorplans? When all the properties are dropped as dupes, the floorplan would be dropped, too. You cannot have both, your requirements are contradictory. How about a comma separated list of properties per floorplan or a list of fl. per prop.?

Comment: one second getting some examples together

Answer (score 3):

You're getting these dups because you're asking for them.

You want

```
   SELECT DISTINCT p.propid, p.*
     FROM property   AS p 
LEFT JOIN floorplans AS f ON p.propid = f.propid
    WHERE f.price BETWEEN [min_price] AND [max_price]
```

When you say `SELECT ..., f.*` you're saying, give me back a row for every distinct combination of `property` and `floorplan`.  But you only want distinct `property` items.

In general, it's a good idea to spell out the particular columns you want. Avoid `p.*` to retrieve all columns.  This is especially true when you're using `SELECT DISTINCT`.

Comment: I'm sure he wants an INNER JOIN, since the conditions are based on information from the floorplans table.

Comment: having problems with the coment thing trying to post some code

Comment: this has to be the worst system of commenting i have ever delt with

Answer (score 2):

I like it better without distinct:

```
SELECT p.*
FROM property AS p 
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT NULL FROM floorplans AS f WHERE f.propid = p.propid AND f.price BETWEEN [min_price] AND [max_price])
```

Comment: OMG your a genius Nikola works great. Perhaps you would care to explain the logic behind it i am not quite getting it. But it does work.

Comment: Sure. Subquery (select in parenthesis) selects rows the usual way with one exception: it is joined to main query by f.propid = p.propid. Exists checks if a row is returned and if so evaluates to true. Use it if you do not need any data from related rows but only need to check if one of them satisfies some condition, because it is often faster than join - it needs only to establish a match and not return any data, hence null in select list (not necessary, but i like it so).

Comment: say I wanted to include data from the floorplans table. Would i be able to use this statment as well just replacing null with the required fields?

Comment: @Dean No, you wouldn't, that's why I asked you in advance in a comment whether you wanted any data from the floorplans table.

Comment: It is not absolutely necessary to have the floorplan data. But the property table dos not contain pricing information so while trying to display the list I suppose I could just pull the floorplans as needed with a second statement, once I have the list of properties retrieved from your previous answer. But if you know how i could do it in a single select statement that would be awesome. However i do know that some join querys that become too complex they take longer to retriev so a second query might be the better option.

Comment: Most likely i will end up loading floorplans dynamically using jQuery.load() But I ask questions not only to fix the problem but to learn new things. and discover as many options as possible

Comment: If I understood your schema correctly, a property has several floors EACH having DIFFERENT price. If this is the case you need another query to get all the floors and their prices. Or you might go with your original one (save changing left to inner join because left is meaningless if you place a condition to right side table) and do some kind of header-list-footer thing on your page.

Comment: Since you like learning - if you need to filter right side table in left join, do it in join itself in ON clause (p.propid = f.propid and f.price between min and max). It will return a property regardless of price, and floorplans within price range. Not something you would do in this instance, obviously...